# Attempting to fresh install ubuntu dual boot rEFInd does not recognize live boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, macosx, refind

Attempted to do a fresh install by following the procedure found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587938 (I ASSuMEd that the fact that it was for vista instead of os x was inconsequential - did I end up making an ASS out of ME?)

Now when rEFInd starts up, I still see the option for osx and ubuntu but no option for installing ubuntu (sorry don't know correct term for that option)

When I click the ubuntu option it says "error: no such partition. entering recovery mode"

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Any and all input would be greatly appreciated!

Furthermore, I attempted to start up gparted again to see if I missed something and now rEFInd isn't seeing it either? Don't know if this is useful info? Does Gparted depend on the presence of Ubuntu?

Comment: The URL to which you link is not a procedure; it's a discussion thread with pointers to outside documentation. It's also almost *five years old!* Given how much has changed in five years, I recommend caution when following advice from such an old forum thread. In sum, it's very unclear what you've done. I can this, though: If you can't see an external installation medium in rEFInd, hit the Esc key. This causes rEFInd to re-scan, which often picks up media it did not initially detect. Beyond that, you must clarify your question, since it's very unclear what your problem is.